# The getMouseWheeldelta function in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to use the getMouseWheeldelta function to use the mouse wheel to switch between images in OpenCV, when mouse wheel scrolled, images to change, but I do not know how to use the function. I keep reading the explanation for it, but nothing. I know how to use the other events for mouse but i want to do this with the mousewheel.Can someone give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great little example which should show how to do it: http://answers.opencv.org/question/128489/mouse-wheel-delta/

I provide you an example code here:

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void on_mouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
    printf("event = %d, %d\n", event, getMouseWheelDelta(flags));
}

int main()
{
    Mat mSrc = imread("xxxxx.jpg");
    imshow("src", mSrc); 
    setMouseCallback( "src", on_mouse, NULL );

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

You would need to switch your images based on the return value of getMouseWheelDelta.